# Rails how to search dropdown selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu

Rails beginner here

I have a bunch of books in a database. I can access each of the books information by appending the book name to my url.
(localhost/3000:books/booktitle1 ... localhost/3000:books/booktitle2 ... etc)

I have a dropdown menu that shows all the books in the database.

```
  <%=select_tag "book", options_from_collection_for_select(@books, "book_name", "book_name")%>
```

How do I make it so that when I make a selection on the drop-down menu, the webpage redirects to that book's information?

Meaning ... select "booktitle1" on dropdown menu, then my browser is sent to localhost/3000:books/booktitle1.

*Edit

It doesn't have to search on form selection exactly, selecting the book and then clicking a "Go" button is completely fine too. Just not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the form is submitted, you need to get the model object for the selected book. Then, get the url path for it. Finally, redirect to that path.

```
book = Book.find(params[:books])
path = url_for(book)
redirect_to path
```

The `params[:books]` returns the book's id, so I can query it using `find`. In your case, you're setting the `value` of your `option` attribute to the book's title. Consider changing that to `id` or use `find_by` to query the model instance. The tag I used is:

```
<%= select_tag 'books', options_from_collection_for_select(@books, 'id', 'title') %>
```

My form looks like this:

```
<%= form_with url: '/books', method: :post do |f| %>
  <%= select_tag 'books', options_from_collection_for_select(@books, 'id', 'title') %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How do I submit my dropdown selection to my controller? Do I have to wrap the dropdown with the form_with helper?

Comment: not necessarily. A vanilla HTML form with the correct `action` and `method` attribute and a `submit` button are sufficient. 
I updated my answer with my form code. If you are new to ruby/rails or web dev in general, I think you would really benefit from [The Odin Project](https://www.theodinproject.com/)

Comment: Gotcha. Just trying to learn as I go but I'm sure I would save a lot of time on these basic concepts. Will check it out. I got this feature working on my site and implemented it in my navbar by putting the logic in my ApplicationController model, really happy with it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working! and that I could be of help.
You are correct in assuming that a structured curriculum would save you a lot of time. Additionally, it would introduce you to other important programming tools (like git) and also familiarize you with accepted conventions and best practices in writing (rails)code. 
For eg: if someone else wanted to change the logic for this feature, she would assume that the logic for this is in the `Books` controller, but you have it in the `Application` controller rn.
I'm glad you got it working & I'm sure you have your plans. Just my two cents :)